# code = marshal.loads(raw_code) ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)

Tags: python, windows, marshalling, facenet

Running flexget Python script I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\project\facenet3\FaceRecognition_SVM_Classifier.py", line 51, in <module>
    model = load_model('D:/project/facenet3/facenet_keras.h5')
  File "C:\Users\tueku\Envs\facenet5\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 67, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\tueku\Envs\facenet5\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py", line 793, in func_load
    code = marshal.loads(raw_code)
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```

Answer (score 2):

This typically happens when you save a model in one Python version (e.g., 3.6) and then try to load that model in another Python version (e.g., 3.9), as the binary serialization that Keras uses ([marshal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html)) is not upwards/downwards compatible. Try to install an old version of Python with an appropriate version of the Tensorflow / Keras libraries. If the model was not trained by yourself, you may ask the creators to export the trained models in a different format that doesn't have these problems, like [ONNX](https://onnx.ai/).